# Play generated PCM data in real time

Tags: c, windows, audio, signal-processing, pcm

I'm  developing a digital audio synthesizer on a dsPIC.

To begin with Im writing and testing the algorithms in matlab.

For the second phase Im translating the algorithms into ANSI C (*MinGW Compiler*) to test on a Windows PC before porting to the dsPIC.

The audio data will be uncompressed PCM samples. What options are there for playing the generated PCM data in C ? (preferably in real time)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Windows, you can use the `waveOut` API.

[Here is a tutorial](http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=4422&lngWId=3).

Comment: Voight :+1 for a solution, although I was hoping there would be a simpler one. I think it just been too long since Ive coded in C! :)

Comment: @volting: This IS the simpler one.  The fancy new one is DirectSound.  Slightly easier on linux (open `/dev/pcm` and use ordinary file writes, although buffering still requires some complexity).